# Gettting all countries information in world using Google API

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api, geolocation

**The Scenario:**
My customer wants to let the users insert their location either by choosing the country, city, region, state, etc.. from dropdowns OR the user can choose the location using [google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/?_ga=2.228048223.35924896.1604984307-193903254.1604984307) and then fill the dropdowns by the data comes from google API after comparing the retrieved values with the values in the dropdowns.

**to accomplish this scenario** I should save all countries Info in a local database to fill dropdowns and of course should be the same names in google API to match it later, and then the user will be able to select their location using dropdowns.

**So, My question** is it possible to get all countries Info from google API or any library based on google API to use it in the dropdowns.

**I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32002230/4977870)** before but the answer is old and the source of data in [Geonames](https://www.geonames.org/) not based on google API, So if I use it I will face a lot of differences in names of the cities, regions, states, etc..

and what I want is to get all countries data based on google API even if this service paid.

**Additional Note:** I Use ( C#, Asp.Net Core, Xamarin Forms, Angular )

Comment: Please, If this question out offtopic, let me know if there is a website I can post my question on it

Comment: As said in the answer you mention, I doubt this is allowed under the licence terms of Google. Have you considered using an OpenStreetMap-based geocoder like Nominatim or Photon ?

Comment: @LéoM Thanks for your quick replay, No I haven't considered using Nominatim, I will read more about it

Comment: I tried to search for an area now using [nominatim.openstreetmap.org](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html)
and I did not find it,

**I think it's not as accurate as Google Maps**

Comment: If I can get all locations in the world  as ( longitude & latitude ) after that I can use GeoCoding from Google